Returning an Eigen SparseMatrix from another function
I am writing a function to return a subset of the columns of a sparse matrix. The returned matrix is also sparse. For my first attempt, I first initialized a sparse matrix
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> x_subset = col_sp(x, index) with
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> col_sp(const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>& x, const std::vector<unsigned int>& index){
    int n_cols=index.size();
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> x_subset(x.rows(),n.cols());
    for(int i=0; i!=x_subset.cols(); ++i){
      x_subset.col(i)=x.col(index[i]);
    }
    return x_subset;
}

However, on compile, I got the following error message
error: static assertion failed: THIS_SPARSE_BLOCK_SUBEXPRESSION_IS_READ_ONLY
  451 |       EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(T)==0, THIS_SPARSE_BLOCK_SUBEXPRESSION_IS_READ_ONLY);

I managed to get it working by declaring x_subset as Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> x_subset(x.rows(),n.cols()); and then passing it by reference into the following function:
void col_sp(Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>& x_subset,
            const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>& x,
            const std::vector<unsigned int>& index) {
  int n_cols = index.size();
   for(int i=0; i!=x_subset.cols(); ++i){
     x_subset.col(i) = x.col(index[i]);
   }
  }

I want to know if there is a way to get the first function working (i.e. return a SparseMatrix instead of passing the SparseMatrix by reference). I prefer the void function for this specific instance, but I would like to know why I received this error message and what, if anything, I can do to avoid it in the future.

Related: C++ Eigen read-only sparse block subexpression? How to write?

If you want fast row-wise access, you should use the RowMajor format. Or use a temporary matrix that is transposed

There is no issue regarding returning vs passing by reference in your examples. The only difference is that you try to write to rows of a sparse column major matrix which is not possible.

Can you compute the inverse of index, i.e. for every row in x determine which row it corresponds to in the result (and maybe -1 if it does not exist)? Then you could much more efficiently through your input matrix and insertBack each value which needs to be in the result (you cannot avoid iterating through every input value, unless you know some specifics about the sparsity pattern). Or as @Homer512 suggested, you can work with RowMajor matrices.

I had a typo in my question. I had an unchanged row_sp function that I copied and forgot to change the middle of the for loop. I've corrected it. The function works when I pass by reference but gives an error when I try to return a matrix.

Assuming you fix the two errors (n.cols() and i!=x_subset.rows()), the original code compiles fine. I cannot reproduce your error.

Thank you for your help (and for the link to that website). My original code compiles when I don't use the function but fails when I call Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> x_subset = col_sp(x, index). Using the website you provided and using the same compiler version as is used in my program, I am able to call Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> x_subset = col_sp(x, index) and compile, so I also cannot reproduce the error on this website. I am using RCpp, but since all of the errors were from the C++ side, I figured the problem was there. I do at least have a functioning workaround.

You need to provide a minimal, reproducible example that can generate the error if you want further help. Also, as a side note: Write @Homer512 (or similar for others) when replying. That way we get notified of your response. Only the person asking gets automatic notifications for new comments (or the person answering when commenting on an answer)

@Homer512 Thank you for your patience and for the help/tips. I am working on translating some code from Armadillo to Eigen, and so was very confused because this function worked as expected using Armadillo. I am still not sure why this function wasn't working properly a few days ago, but I retried today and was finally able to compile the code which used the function that returns an Eigen::SparseMatrix without getting the weird static assertion failure.
